# SSIS - Parent variable value not passed to child

Tags: ssis, package

I'm trying to pass parent variable to child package using Package Deployment Model. I have double checked the name, the spelling,the configuration but with no luck. The value is always 1 as set in the child package(expected 0 in the parent package).
Can any one tell me what I have missed?

**PARENT:**
[image: PARENT CONFIGURATION]

**CHILD:**
[image: CHILD]

[image: CHILD SCRIPT]

[image: CHILD VARIABLE]

Comment: did you set it to pass in the first image? It doesn't happen without you setting it to happen.

Comment: @KeithL How to set pass in the first image?

Comment: I posted an image of where to pass parameters in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the execute package task in the parent you set parameter bindings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks，but I cannot add in this page. The ‘Add‘ button is disabled. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you map the package on the prior page?

Comment: What do you mean by mapping? I'm using the Package Deployment Model, I just simply put the execute package task in the parent package and reference the child package as file system.